# Matching string using variable in regular expression with $ and ^

Tags: javascript, regex

This is probably a very easy question to answer, but I haven't figure out what is the correct way to do it.

I need to match a text via regular expressions using `^ and $` to only match elements starting and finishing with that string. However, I need to be able to do that using a variable:

```
var name // some variable
var re = new RegExp(name,"g");
```

So I'd like to match every string that includes completely (from beginning to end) my variable `name`, but I don't want to match strings containing at some place my variable `name`.

How can I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var strtomatch = "something";
var name = '^something$';
var re = new RegExp(name,"gi");
document.write(strtomatch.match(re));
```

The `i` is for ignoring case.
This matches just word "something" and will not match somethingelse.

if you are looking to match it in the middle of a sentence, you should use the following in your code

```
var name = ' something ';
```

Alernately, using word boundaries,

```
var name = '\\bsomething\\b';
```

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/mc6PX/1/)**

Comment: Not really. I want to match strings at the beginning of a line. I will clarify that point.

Comment: But I want to do that using a variable (in my example, var name).

Comment: Better, but that doesn't work. By the way, 'something' was just an example. Ideally, I would have something like name = '^' + name + '$'.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Almost there... why is this not working http://jsfiddle.net/Gpm2M/2/ ?

Comment: @RobertSmith - That fiddle doesn't "work" because your regex has a space in it: `/\b something/gi`.

Comment: Sure, I put it there. I also want to match that and also "something ".

Comment: @RobertSmith - If there's a space in your regex it _won't_ match strings that don't have a space in them. And you're testing a string that doesn't have a space. In your case you've also got a `\b` word boundary match _before_ the space, so it will only match against a string that ends with a word boundary then a space then "something".

Comment: You were not escaping the \ character in that string. That is why the older fiddle was not working. This one is correct.

Comment: I think I was escaping it: name = '\\b' + string + '$' but I got confused between strtomatch and string :-)

Answer (score 3):

If you're saying you want to match `something` at the beginning *or* end of the string then do this:

```
/^something|something$/
```

With your variable:

```
new RegExp("^" + name + "|" + name + "$");
```

EDIT: For your updated question, you want the `name` variable to be the entire string matched, so:

```
new RegExp("^" + name + "$"); // note: the "g" flag from your question
                              // is not needed if matching the whole string
```

But that is pointless unless `name` contains a regular expression itself because although you could say:

```
var strToTest = "something",
    name = "something",
    re = new RegExp("^" + name + "$");

if (re.test(strToTest)) {
   // do something
}
```

You could also just say:

```
if (strToTest === name) {
   // do something
}
```

**EDIT 2:** OK, from your comment you seem to be saying that the regex should match where "something" appears anywhere in your test string as a discrete word, so:

```
"something else"           // should match
"somethingelse"            // should not match
"This is something else"   // should match
"This is notsomethingelse" // should not match
"This is something"        // should match
"This is something."       // should match?
```

If that is correct then:

```
re = new RegExp("\\b" + name + "\\b");
```

Comment: re = new RegExp("^" + name + "$") works fine, but I also want to match "... something ..."

Comment: OK, I've updated my answer with one last attempt to guess what you want. This whole process would've been so much easier if you'd included some concrete examples in your question, similar to what I've now added to my answer.

Comment: Yes, that's what I want. Seconds later than DarkXphenomenon's answer, but definitely +1 :-) Thanks for all your help.

Comment: You're welcome. Note that xdazz's answer basically said the same thing 28 minutes ago...

Answer (score 1):

You should use `/\bsomething\b/`. `\b` is to match the word boundary.

```
"A sentence using something".match(/\bsomething\b/g);
```