# RegExp using regex + variables

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I know there are many questions about variables in regex. Some of them for instance:

- [concat variable in regexp pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13068981/concat-variable-in-regexp-pattern)
- [Variables in regexp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15843539/variables-in-regexp)
- [How to properly escape characters in regexp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663987/how-to-properly-escape-characters-in-regexp)
- [Matching string using variable in regular expression with $ and ^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11489396/matching-string-using-variable-in-regular-expression-with-and)

Unfortunately none of them explains in detail how to escape my RegExp.

Let's say I want to find all files that have this string before them:

```
file:///storage/sdcard0/
```

I tried this with regex:

```
(?:file:\/\/\/storage\/sdcard0\(.*))(?:\"|\')
```

which correctly got my image1.jpg and image2.jpg in certain json file. (tried with http://regex101.com/#javascript)

For the life of me I can't get this to work inside JS. I know you should use [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) to solve this, but I'm having issues.

```
var findStr =  "file:///storage/sdcard0/";
var regex =  "(?:"+ findStr +"(.*))(?:\"|\')";
var re = new RegExp(regex,"g"); 
var result = <mySearchStringVariable>.match(re);
```

With this I get 1 result and it's wrong (bunch of text). I reckon I should escape this as said all over the web.. I tried to escape findStr with both functions below and the result was the same. So I thought OK I need to escape some chars inside regex also.

I tried to manually escape them and the result was no matches.

I tried to escape the whole regex variable before passing it to RegExp constructor and the result was the same: no matches.

```
function quote(regex) {
  return regex.replace(/([()[{*+.$^\\|?])/g, '\\$1');
}   

function escapeRegExp(str) {
    return str.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&");
}
```

What the hell am I doing wrong, please?

Is there any good documentation on how to write RegExp with variables in it?

Comment: Why are you including the quote characters at the end of your pattern? That doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Quote is the ending character of my match, the point where I want to stop matching..

Comment: Actually your regex works perfectly well for me. You're going to have to post more detail.

Comment: When I do `"foo bar file:///storage/sdcard0/'".match(re)` I get the correct result, in other words - just the file URL and not the "foo bar".

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to escape regular expression in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593637/how-to-escape-regular-expression-in-javascript)

Comment: @Pointy string to search from is received with var string = JSON.stringify(json); - could this be a problem?

Comment: Ahhhh - i figured it out!! I needed to use LAZY with (.*?) 

damn never thought of that before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I needed to do was use LAZY instead of greedy with

```
var regex =  "(?:"+ findStr +"(.*?))(?:\"|\')"; // added ? in (.*?)
```